# How to expand an object in an array in JavaScirpt

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to expand array in JavaScript.
The object ↓

```
const tests = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'taro',
        designs: [
            {
                designId: 1,
                designName: "design1"
            },
            {
                designId: 2,
                designName: "design2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'John',
        designs: [
            {
                designId: 3,
                designName: "design3"
            },
            {
                designId: 4,
                designName: "design4"
            }
        ]
    },
{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Lisa',
        designs: []
    },
];
```

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'taro', designId: 1, designName: 'design1' },
  { id: 1, name: 'taro', designId: 2, designName: 'design2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', designId: 3, designName: 'design3' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', designId: 4, designName: 'design4' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Lisa', designId: null, designName: null },
]
```

It is easy to do this using double for, but I want to use it with higher-order functions.

The code I wrote

```
for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < tests[i].designs.length; j++) {
        const id = tests[i].id
        const name = tests[i].name
        result.push({
            id,
            name,
            designId: tests[i].designs[j].designId,
            designName: tests[i].designs[j].designName
        })
    }
}
```

In addition, it would be appreciated if you could additionally explain the difference in performance between double for and higher-order functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and ***expected output*** using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.flatMap()` on your tests array with an inner `.map()` on each `designs` array. The inner map on the designs array will take the properties from the currently iterated design object and merge it with the properties from the parent object. The outer `.flatMap()` can then be used to concatenate all returned maps into the one array:

```js
const tests = [ { id: 1, name: 'taro', designs: [ { designId: 1, designName: "design1" }, { designId: 2, designName: "design2" } ] }, { id: 2, name: 'John', designs: [ { designId: 3, designName: "design3" }, { designId: 4, designName: "design4" } ] }, ];

const res = tests.flatMap(({designs, ...rest}) => designs.map(design => ({
  ...rest,
  ...design
})));
console.log(res);
```

Edit:
If you need `null` values to appear for your design objects if your designs array is empty, you can add the keys explicitly to a new object that you can return when the designs array is empty:

```js
const tests = [ { id: 1, name: 'taro', designs: [] }, { id: 2, name: 'John', designs: [] }, ];

const res = tests.flatMap(({designs, ...rest}) => 
  designs.length 
    ? designs.map(design => ({
       ...rest,
       ...design
      }))
    : {...rest, designId: null, designName: null}
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ah... flatMap, that's indeed better

Comment: @Nick I want to fill the designId and designName with null even if the mojidesigns is an empty array. `[{ id: 1, name: 'taro', designs: [] } ] → [{ id: 1, name: 'taro', designId: null, designName: null }]`

Comment: @Lana2548 you can check for an empty designs array, and then return an object with `null` for designId + name (I've provided an edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Array.reduce` function with `Array.map` to generate the array:

```js
const results = tests.reduce((acc, { designs, ...rest }) => [
  ...acc,
  ...designs.map(e => ({ ...rest, ...e }))
], []);
```

```js
const tests = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'taro',
        designs: [
            {
                designId: 1,
                designName: "design1"
            },
            {
                designId: 2,
                designName: "design2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'John',
        designs: [
            {
                designId: 3,
                designName: "design3"
            },
            {
                designId: 4,
                designName: "design4"
            }
        ]
    },
];

const results = tests.reduce((acc, { designs, ...rest }) => [
  ...acc,
  ...designs.map(e => ({ ...rest, ...e }))
], []);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the higher-order function [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const newArr = tests.reduce((prev, {designs, ...current}) => [
   ...prev, ...designs.map(design => ({...design,...current}));
]      
, []);
```

The performance in your approach and this higher-order approach is the same because `Array.prototype.reduce` runs through the whole array and just facilitates the `initialValue` approach for us.